# Select statement to retrieve language count with conditions

Tags: mysql

I need to display countries language counts that have more then one official language or more then 2 unofficial languages. This is what I would like to do but don't know how to properly write it. Any help would be awesome.

```
SELECT 
                CountryCode, 
                IsOfficial,
                COUNT(Language) as LangCount

FROM    countrylanguage
WHERE   IsOfficial = 'T' 
GROUP BY CountryCode
HAVING COUNT(Language) > 1
OR
WHERE IsOfficial = 'F'
GROUP BY CountryCode
HAVING COUNT(Language) > 2  
ORDER BY CountryCode
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do the conditions as part of a compound having

```
SELECT CountryCode, 
       IsOfficial,
       COUNT(Language) as LangCount
FROM countrylanguage
GROUP BY isOfficial, CountryCode
HAVING (COUNT(language) > 1 AND isOfficial = 'T')
    OR (COUNT(language) > 2 AND isOfficial = 'F')
```

You can't have multiple group by and having clauses so you combine the conditions.

Now if a country has both, both records will be returned.  If a country has only one of the two criteria, then only that record will be returned.  Is this what you want?  (This is why sample data and expected results helps.)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by `group by and having`

```
select 
  CountryCode
from countrylanguage
group by CountryCode having 
  sum(case when isofficial = "T" then 1 else 0 end) > 1 or 
  sum(case when isofficial = "F" then 1 else 0 end) > 2
```

[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09f46b/1)

Comment: Looks good but what if  they want isofficial in the results?  Just need to add that the the select and group by right?

Comment: Yes you are right,,, If those fields are needed then select and group by...

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION ALL to combine your two queries into one. UNION ALL will not merge the results and faster compared to UNION which removes duplicates.

```
SELECT 
            CountryCode, 
            IsOfficial,
            COUNT(Language) as LangCount
FROM    countrylanguage
WHERE   IsOfficial = 'T' 
GROUP BY CountryCode, IsOfficial
HAVING COUNT(Language) > 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 
            CountryCode, 
            IsOfficial,
            COUNT(Language) as LangCount
FROM    countrylanguage
WHERE IsOfficial = 'F'
GROUP BY CountryCode, IsOfficial
HAVING COUNT(Language) > 2  
ORDER BY CountryCode
```